# Appending data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, append

Question: I have a table that has a column called `DOB`. In it is well... dates of birth, but in a format such as `04/22/1987`. I'd like to change them to `19870422`, which would entail moving the 4 digit year to the front of the cell and deleting the / marks and leaving no spaces.

Any suggestions in an efficient was to do this would be much appreciated.  thanks everyone!

Comment: Just to be clear is the date a varchar or of date type?

Comment: it is varchar in those cells.

Comment: but don't look at it as a "date"  just take it as text. Basicall I just want to move the last 4 digits to the front. I'll run a simple replace command to dump out the / marks...

Comment: Please don't change it from one horrible string format to another (less horrible) string format. Since those are **dates**, look like dates, quack like date - **make them** an appropriate datatype, like...... `DATE` !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table is called `Foo` and your column name is `DOB`:

```
Update Foo
Set DOB = Substring(DOB, 7, 4) + Substring(DOB, 1, 2) + Substring(DOB, 4, 2);
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7b7ab/2).

Note that this will update the `DOB` column for all rows in your table. So, be certain that all of your data is in the format `MM/DD/YYYY` before changing it to `YYYYMMDD`.

Note that the [`Substring()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) function takes three parameters:

1. Input (often text, but could be binary)
2. Starting point (which is one-based)
3. Total number of characters to return.

So, the expression `Substring(DOB, 7, 4)` starts at the seventh position (the beginning of the year) and takes four characters (the four-character year.)

Answer (score 0):

Select Convert(char(8),dob,112) dob

Comment: If column is varchar change to Select Convert(char(8),cast(dob as datetime),112) dob

Comment: The table name is testfile and I'm getting an error saying bad syntax near DOB... which is the column name...

Comment: Select dbo.testfile convert(char(8),cast(DOB as datetime),112) dob

Comment: Sorry about short reply I'm typing on a mobile phone.  after the select statement I wrote above, type From dbo.testfile.  That should display the date as you want it.  Are you looking to update this column or just display it in the new format?

Comment: If you run the statement as i've said above and make sure it's formatting correctly.  So you want the SELECT.. FROM TESTFILE

Answer (score 0):

So you want to update all rows within the date column basically updating the existing columns

```
UPDATE YourTable SET YourNewColumn = CONVERT(DATETIME,YourOldColumn,112)
```

Comment: its a date of dirth column not a date column per se.